# Fetching database to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm very beginner and doing small project to fetch mysql database table using node.js to webpage.

I been following one tutorial and I was confused how the script is written inside html between `<% %>` these symbols. When I tried like that, for me it didn't recognised as a script.

Could someone explain how to make it work? Do I need to install anything additional for it to work? Would appreciate for any advice!

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>S.N</th>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>

  <% 
     if (userData.length != 0) {
       var i = 1;
       userData.forEach(function(data){
  %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= i %></td>
      <td><%=data.fullName %></td>
      <td><%=data.emailAddress %></td>
      <td><%=data.city %></td>
      <td><%=data.country %></td>
      <td><a href="/users/edit/<%=data.id%>">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a href="/users/delete/<%=data.id%>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  i++; }) %>
  else { %>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
    </tr>
  <% } %>
</table>
```

When I refresh my webpage with script written like it shows as a text on the webpage instead of giving functionality.

I know that script in html written between `<script></script>` tags, but in youtube video dude was showing this way, but didn't explain about it.

Comment: You have to configure your webserver to run your page through node.js parser. You have to check out node.js installation guides for your webserver and operating system.

Comment: It's likely it's an EJS template. *(With syntax errors.)*

Comment: “Could someone explain how to make it work?” — I’d be surprised if the tutorial you are following (but haven’t referenced) didn’t explain that. It’s **very** unlikely that it would dive straight into EJS which depends on external data without covering how to get that data and pass it to EJS.

Answer (score -1):

I presume you are trying to EJS templating.  Have you installed the correct version of EJS (npm install ejs) on your server side in that case? Check for any parsing errors on the server console when you encounter the render error on the browser.